# com.isomorphic.datasource.* and com.smartgwt.client.data.*, how do they differ?

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, smartgwt-pro

Basically I am trying to understand the scenario when which DataSource to choose between ***com.isomorphic.datasource.DataSource*** and ***com.smartgwt.client.data.DataSource***

I see that some functions like setProgressiveLoading is not available in isomorphic as in smartGWT package. So is it to be understood that smartGWT classes to be preffered?

Answer (score 0):

I think you must first understand that com.smartgwt.client.* are client side APIs, while the others are server side APIs.